# Where is the appropriate place to deploy web apps?

Tags: administration, deployment

I am a new sysadmin (by default). We have an ubuntu 14 server with two users. Both users need to deploy web apps to the (production) server. My plan is to create a folder off of root

```
/apps/
```

and then put each app in a folder there. Then add each user to a group and give that group permissions to read and write in that folder?

Is that the clean/standard way to do this? Am I missing something? Interested in doing this properly.

Comment: Developers should never be touching production directly. You should setup an interface for code deployment eg jenkins, puppet, chef, etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to FHS `/srv` is where [network service data/scripts should be stored](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM). But it really depends on the OS and commonly accepted conventions of wherever you work (They do the `/apps` thing where I work for instance).

Permissions are also going to be specific to a particular workplace. I would suggest using POSIX and/or NFS ACL's but there's no single answer to that. It depends on what controls you need and what's easier for you guys to wrap your heads around.

**EDIT:**

I can offer some more generic advice:

- If you use only standard permissions, make sure you `chmod g+s` each directory so that members of the same workgroup can have appropriate access to these folders and files they create are still owned by the workgroup and not some private group the owning user is in.
- If you use POSIX ACL's make sure you set default ACL's on the directories so that all the workgroups have access no matter what.
- Always spot check. Have some 3-4 operations you can run as the various users that have known results. You don't have to go overboard but it's always good to do some kind of dry run before you tell people to use something.

Comment: what about users/groups

Comment: just updated the answer, try reloading.

Comment: updated again, btw